# Найти одинаковые значения с двух массивов и добавить класс JS

Tags: javascript, массивы

Помогите пожалуйста с задачей.
Есть один массив со значением кодов стран и есть второй массив со значениями стран которые необходимо выделить
нужно добавить класс **active** к тому элементу, который совпадает по значению.
Спасибо большое.

Код:

```
let itemIDs = []
let countryIDs = []
let mapItem = document.querySelectorAll('.world-map__item')
let mapCountry = document.querySelectorAll('.map-country')

mapItem.forEach( el => {
    itemIDs.push(el.dataset.countryId)
});

mapCountry.forEach( el => {
    countryIDs.push(el.getAttribute('id'))
});

mapCountry.forEach( el => {
    let id = el.getAttribute('id')

    ?????????????????????????

    if(id == itemIDs) {
        el.classList.add('active')
    }
});
```

Comment: itemIDs.forEach(itemIDs => { if (id == itemIDs) ... }) пробовали?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно заменить

```
if(id == itemIDs) {
    el.classList.add('active')
}
```

на

```
el.classList[itemIDs.includes(id) ? 'add' : 'remove']('active');
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1):

Если все верно понял то так можно

```
let mapItem = document.querySelectorAll('.world-map__item')

[].map.call(
  mapItem,
  el => {
    let id = el.dataset.countryId;
    let Country = document.getElementByID(id);
    if(Country) Country.classList.add('active');

  }
);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, я уже нашел решение